# Apriori algorithm in Perl

Tags: perl

I am new to Perl and trying to write a [Apriori algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm) in Perl. Initially I created a hash table to get frequency of each items, but then how do I create hash table with keys holding all the pairs of items? I mean how can I find frequent item sets?

This is the code I wrote so far.

```
open(IN,"dataset-1.txt");   
my %words;
while (my $line = <IN>)
{
   foreach my $word (split /\s+/, $line)
   {
        $words{$word}++;
   }
}
foreach my $word (keys %words)
{
    print "$word: $words{$word}\n";
}
```

The dataset I am using is the following:

```
mango onion nintendo chain eggs
doll onion nintendo
mango apple chain
mango umbrella chain
corn chain cream eggs
```

and the second step I am trying to do is create a hash table with all possible combinations of items as keys and values should be the frequency of item set in each line. Can you help me please?

Comment: The Apriori algorithm requires more than one set, you are loading everything into a large single set. *All* the pairs, triplets etc in this large set exist precisely once.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question on how to take all possible combinations of items, you can use the [Algorithm::Combinatorics](http://search.cpan.org/~fxn/Algorithm-Combinatorics-0.27/Combinatorics.pm) module.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(subsets);

my %freq; #save the frequencies
open (my $IN,'<','dataset-1.txt') or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
    chomp;
    my @words=sort split/\s+/;
    my @itemsets=subsets(\@words); #we take every subset of the items of each row
    for (@itemsets) {
        $freq{join(',',@$_)}++;
    }
}
close $IN;

for (sort {$freq{$b}<=>$freq{$a}} keys %freq) { #print the frequency
    next if $_ eq ''; #skip empty itemset if present
    print "$_=>$freq{$_}\n";
}
```

For your dataset, this will print:

```
chain=>4
mango=>3
chain,mango=>3
onion=>2
chain,eggs=>2
eggs=>2
nintendo,onion=>2
nintendo=>2
chain,eggs,mango,onion=>1
chain,eggs,mango=>1
eggs,nintendo=>1
cream,eggs=>1
chain,corn=>1
doll,onion=>1
chain,umbrella=>1
eggs,nintendo,onion=>1
chain,cream=>1
eggs,mango=>1
eggs,mango,onion=>1
chain,corn,eggs=>1
corn,cream,eggs=>1
umbrella=>1
mango,nintendo,onion=>1
chain,eggs,nintendo=>1
mango,nintendo=>1
chain,cream,eggs=>1
apple,mango=>1
chain,nintendo,onion=>1
chain,corn,cream,eggs=>1
doll,nintendo,onion=>1
chain,eggs,nintendo,onion=>1
chain,mango,nintendo=>1
chain,eggs,mango,nintendo=>1
corn=>1
cream=>1
doll=>1
chain,eggs,mango,nintendo,onion=>1
chain,mango,onion=>1
chain,onion=>1
mango,onion=>1
chain,corn,cream=>1
corn,cream=>1
doll,nintendo=>1
apple=>1
chain,mango,nintendo,onion=>1
apple,chain=>1
apple,chain,mango=>1
eggs,mango,nintendo,onion=>1
eggs,mango,nintendo=>1
corn,eggs=>1
mango,umbrella=>1
chain,mango,umbrella=>1
eggs,onion=>1
chain,nintendo=>1
chain,eggs,onion=>1
```

Please note that this is not the *Apriori algorithm*, it's just the answer to your question. But knowing how to make combinations it should be easy to take it from there, define a *support* threshold, purge the itemsets with lower frequencies, and continue.

Now, since the Apriori is used to derive [association rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning), you can skip all the pain and use the [Tree::FP](http://search.cpan.org/~nitram/Tree-FP-0.04/FP.pm) module (which implements a [Frequent-Pattern Tree](http://hareenlaks.blogspot.gr/2011/06/fp-tree-example-how-to-identify.html)). I tried it today and unfortunately found that it is buggy (depending on the dataset and the defined support threshold might throw an error), still the following code works and returns the rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Tree::FP;
use POSIX qw(ceil);

my %words;
my $min_sup=20; #support is defined to find "large" itemsets. just an example, choose your own values!
my $min_conf=60; #confidence is defined to find "strong" associations. just an example, choose your own values!
{
    open (my $IN,'<','dataset-1.txt') or die $!;
    while (<$IN>) {
        chomp;
        $words{$_}++ for split/\s+/;
    }
    close $IN;
}
my @sorted=sort {$words{$b}<=>$words{$a}} keys %words; #we prune itemsets with frequencies inferior to the minimum support and sort them by frequency
my $fptree=Tree::FP->new(@sorted); #create a new Frequent-Pattern Tree
$fptree->set_support($min_sup/100); #set support
$fptree->set_confidence($min_conf/100); #set confidence (note: it actually doesn't filter the results as expected; known issue of the module)
{ #populate the tree
    open (my $IN,'<','dataset-1.txt') or die $!;
    while (<$IN>) {
        chomp;
        $fptree->insert_tree(split/\s+/) or die "Error while insert row $.: ",$fptree->err;
    }
    close $IN;
}
my @rules=$fptree->association_rules;
for (@rules) {
    next if $_->confidence < $fptree->confidence;
    print '{',join(',',$_->left),'} => {',join(',',$_->right),'} ',sprintf('support:%.2f, confidence:%.2f',$_->support,$_->confidence),"\n";
}
```

Comment: Hi Thank you very much for the reply. your work is really helpful. But one last thing I am not able run the code. It is showing me errors. I don't understand why...can you please suggest me anything

Comment: this is the error I am getting for first program i.e finding all possible frequencies.                                                       Undefined subroutine &main::subsets called at code1 line 7, <$IN> line 1.

Comment: And these for algorithm code                                             ..Semicolon seems to be missing at apcode line 21.
syntax error at apcode line 9, near "own values"
syntax error at apcode line 11, near "own values"
Can't use global $! in "my" at apcode line 13, near "die $!"
syntax error at apcode line 19, near "}"
syntax error at apcode line 22, near "frequency
syntax error at apcode line 26, near "module)
Can't use global $! in "my" at apcode line 28, near "die $!"

Comment: The 1st error means that you forgot the line `use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(subsets);` in the beginning of your script. Make sure also that you've installed the Module (in case you don't know how to install modules, search google about "perl install modules").

Comment: 2nd error means that something is seriously messed up with the code that you have pasted. I've tested both of the codes that I gave you here, so make sure again that you copied properly! and let me know